# SSRS report in the Iframe in classic ASP does not work correctly

Tags: iframe, reporting-services, asp-classic

I am not sure how I can upload a screen shot here. But I will tell my problem.
I have a legacy application which is written in classic asp. It has to show an SSRS report in the iframe. The view source look as below:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<DIV>
Somethings blah blah here....
</DIV>
<IFRAME height=500 src="URL" width=820 align=center>
</IFRAME>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The problem is, when the report has two pages and when the user tries to scroll down the second page, the first page of the report overlaps the second one. How this problem can be solved? Any suggestions?

Let me know how I can upload screen shots. That might better explain.

EDIT: The problem is just with the SSRS report. Nothing to do with the IFrame or classic asp. I opened the report URL separately in a window and reduced the internet explorer's size and I could see the same problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said above, the problem was occuring from the SSRS report.
I removed the  property and this is fixed